# iOS 13.6 beta configuration not supported on Xcode 12 beta

Tags: xcode, flutter, xcode12, ios13.6

I'm trying to run my app on my iPad 11 (running iOS 13.6 public beta), however, when build is successful Xcode shows an error saying please reconnect your iPad. Also when I go to Window > Devices and Simulators I see the following:
[image]

FYI: I built my app using flutter and the app works fine in the simulator.

Comment: Give a try with latest Xcode 11?

Comment: Should be solved with Xcode 12 beta 2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-beta-release-notes/

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me, I solved with a workaround...it's beta so I think this trick is allowed :P

Anyway, you cannot skip Xcode 11.6 beta so you need it.

- Download Xcode 11.6 beta
- Run your app using this Xcode (check Preference > Location > Command Line tool is 11.6)
- Quit Xcode 11.6, Open Xcode 12 and now you can run your app on iOS13.6 and later (even iOS14)... if you like you can also change the Command Line Tool to 12.

Hope this helps, I was stuck on this since I had Xcode from App Store 11.5 and skipped to Xcode beta.

Bye